# CloudFormation - always use latest AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami, ssm

The blog post [Query for the latest Amazon Linux AMI IDs using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) describes how to always reference the latest version of an distribution in a CloudFormation template.

```
# Use public Systems Manager Parameter
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: '/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2'

Resources:
 Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
```

How would that work for other distributions like RedHat and CentOS?
What would be the parameter store path to use?

Answer (score 17):

As @John Rotenstein said, SSM seems to only have Amazon Linux AMIs. But you can still get others with [DescribeImages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html). You can then create a custom resource to query it for you and use the result as the AMI value.

```
Resources:
  DescribeImagesRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: DescribeImages
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Action: ec2:DescribeImages
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: "*"
  GetLatestAMI:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: python3.6
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !Sub ${DescribeImagesRole.Arn}
      Timeout: 60
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          import cfnresponse
          import json
          import traceback

          def handler(event, context):
            try:
              response = boto3.client('ec2').describe_images(
                  Owners=[event['ResourceProperties']['Owner']],
                  Filters=[
                    {'Name': 'name', 'Values': [event['ResourceProperties']['Name']]},
                    {'Name': 'architecture', 'Values': [event['ResourceProperties']['Architecture']]},
                    {'Name': 'root-device-type', 'Values': ['ebs']},
                  ],
              )

              amis = sorted(response['Images'],
                            key=lambda x: x['CreationDate'],
                            reverse=True)
              id = amis[0]['ImageId']

              cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, {}, id)
            except:
              traceback.print_last()
              cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAIL, {}, "ok")
  CentOSAmi:
    Type: Custom::FindAMI
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Sub ${GetLatestAMI.Arn}
      Owner: "679593333241"
      Name: "CentOS Linux 7 x86_64 HVM EBS *"
      Architecture: "x86_64"
```

You would update the values in `CentOSAmi` so you can find the right AMI and then use the output with:

```
ImageId: !Ref CentOSAmi
```

Answer (score 3):

Those parameter store AMI values appear to be hand-managed by AWS. I've only found references to:

- [Amazon Linux](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/)
- [Windows](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/query-for-the-latest-windows-ami-using-systems-manager-parameter-store/)
- [ECS](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/new/2018/amazon-ecs-provides-ecs-optimized-ami-metadata-via-ssm-parameter/)

**Update:** There are now more services available:

[image]